# Remove Duplicate entry ''' for key '' warning

Tags: php, mysql

I have a unique key set for a mysql database row so not to insert duplicate entries on a form submit. That works fine, but if there's a duplicate entry the page doesn't load. Instead the user receives the warning: `Duplicate entry ''' for key ''`

How do I go about turning that error off and loading the page even if there is a duplicate key, while still using the unique key on the row? I tried setting error report to off, but that didn't work.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user
(formemail,UserIP,Timestamp,LP) VALUES('$email','$userip',NOW(),'$lp') ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Your error-producing query please

Comment: Normally, check before the query if the records exists. If it does, do not proceed. Probably you get an error by trying to execute the query empty or some other condition. Check first, then proceed

Comment: updated OP with query  @AlexiosTsiaparas I thought this was the purpose of setting the unique key, to avoid having to do that? I'm not debating, but asking because I'm a novice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your SQL insert to use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) so that the error isn't generated in the first place.

Don't try to hide the symptom, treat the problem.

Also, I must point out that the [mysql library is being deprecated](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and should not be used for new code, you should, at the least, use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or, preferably [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo). There is a good [tutorial on PDO here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) if you are interested in learning.

Comment: Thanks! This worked  `
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE formemail=formemail;") 
 or die(mysql_error()); `